# Test url availability with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

Is it possible through jQuery (or plain javascript) to test if a webpage on another domain is available?
I tried getting the response headers with an ajax-call but I get an error no matter what site outside my own domain I test.

So do I really need a proxy script on my server or would I be able to skip that request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes,** you need to use a proxy script on your server. JavaScript cannot be used in a browser to request resources across domains, as per [the same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: I believe I read somewhere that you could get access to the headers - and that's really all I need. If that isn't possible why is that? Would it be a security risk if I could see if the response was 200 or not?

Comment: This, taken by word, is not true. You *can* request resources across domains; just think about iframes, img tags with src pointing to another domain, or styles and scripts (e.g. jQuery included from remote location). Actually there is a way around to see if a site is available, however I couldn't get it to work with MSIE yet.

Comment: @Powerslave this answer is really just out of date: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @MattBall It might and might as well not be the case. CORS is not a proper standard yet and there might be a need to have some kind of workaround for browsers that do not support CORS. Also, you might not have control over the source/behaviour settings of the remote site and still need to check if it's alive or not.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible through jQuery (or plain javascript) to test if a webpage on another domain is available?

Due to [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you need a proxy/bridge on your server unless the remote server implements [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which obviously we cannot assume for the general case.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `<img>` tag that points to an existing image on the external domain.

If the `onerror` event fires, image, and perhaps the entire site, is down.

If it fires after 5 seconds or so, it probably timed out, so the entire site is likely to be down.

Comment: What if there is no image on the remote domain? The onerror will fire and yet this is not an indication that the domain is not alive.

Comment: @Darin: That's why I wrote `(or the image)`.

Comment: in this case you shouldn't write `the site (or the image) is down`, you should write `the image is down` as that's the only objective conclusion we could make provided this observation (sorry for my nitpicking :-)).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It does not necessarily have to be an image to load as an image. It will be corrupt as an image, still valid as an HTTP request. For example, `<script>` tag works fine in this case. It will fire a `SyntaxError` as HTML gets parsed instead of the expected JS, but `onerror` won't get called, unless there's a problem with the request indeed. Bad news is, in IE it does not work: `onerror` is never invoked. In Firefox, it works just fine. Another bad news is, due to the event-driven nature of this solution, one can't write a synchronous `isWorking(url)` function.